# Creating a Macro to bring up the AutoFilter Dialog Box

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I'm using Excel 2010, and I'm attempting to create a Macro that will allow me to open the AutoFilter's Text Filter -> Contains dialog box (always searching one column), or any dialog box that will allow me to enter a string of text and return the rows that contain that string.  According to the Googling I've done so far, it looks like a VBA script will be necessary, but I'd rather steer as clear from that as possible, as I have no experience in it.

The data is located between A2 and F25000 - A1-F1 are the AutoFilter headers.  Thanks in advance for help anyone can offer.

Best Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will open up the custom auto-filter dialogue box.

```
ExecuteExcel4Macro "filter?(1)"
```

"(1)" in the code is the column to filter (column A).

This is is like clicking the down arrow in an auto-filtered list and then selecting "Custom Filter".